# what would this be as an if statement

Tags: java

```
private String adjustDirection(String direction) {

        return (currentFloor == Building.FLOORS)
                ? "down"
                : ((currentFloor == 1) ? "up" : direction);
    }
```

Hi, I'm having a hard time understanding this, what would be an easier way to write it ?

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about the Conditional (ternary) operator in the return statement? If (condition is true) { do if true } else { do if not true  } is the same as (condition is true ? do if true : do if not true). That help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ternary operator" basically is shorthand for `if-then-else`, in this case a nested `if-then-else`, but you can actually shortcut by return:

```
private String adjustDirection(String direction) {
    if ( currentFloor == Building.FLOORS) return "down";
    if ( currentFloor == 1) return "up";
    return direction;
}
```

If however you happen to be under the rule of a "single return" policy, you can also use the if/elseif:

```
private String adjustDirection(String direction) {
    string returnValue = direction;
    if ( currentFloor == Building.FLOORS){
       returnValue = "down";
    }
    else if ( currentFloor == 1) { 
       returnValue = "up";
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

A "literal" unroll of the shorthand would then be:

```
private String adjustDirection(String direction) {
    string returnValue;
    if ( currentFloor == Building.FLOORS){
       returnValue = "down";
    }
    else {
       if ( currentFloor == 1) {
          returnValue = "up";
       }
       else {
          returnValue = direction;
       }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called the ternary operator

To make it simple:

```
private String adjustDirection(String direction) {

    if (currentFloor == Building.FLOORS) return "down";
    if (currentFloor == 1) return "up";
    return direction;
}
```

For ternary operation example,

```
if a==5
 b=5
else 
 b=10
```

can be written as

```
a == 5 ? b = 5 : b = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the conditional operator. It's an alternative method of using if-else.

```
condition?true_statement:false_statement;
```

This translates to:

```
if(condition){
    true_statement;
}else{
    false_statement;
}
```

What you see is a case of nested conditional operator.